# Form doesn't submit some textareas and number fields on live server, but does on localhost

Tags: php, html, web

I am trying to make an application form. Everything works perfectly on localhost but lately, as I began testong on the live site, I've noticed how certain textareas or input fields don't get passed to $_POST when the form is submitted.

A snippet of the form:

```
<form id="apply" action="parseApplication.php" novalidate method="request">
      <div class="app-box basic fade">

        <p class="required"></p>
        <input type="text" name="First name" placeholder="John" required><br>
        <p class="required"></p>
        <input type="text" name="Last name" placeholder="Doe" required><br>
        <p class="required"></p>
        <input type="number" name="Age" id="age"required><br>
        <p class="required"></p>
        <input type="text" name="Twitter handle" placeholder="@username" required><br>

        <p></p>
        <select id="position" name="Position">
          <option value="support-rep">Support Representative</option>
          <option value="moderator">Moderator</option>
          <option value="build">Build Team Member</option>
          <option value="dev">Developer</option>
        </select>

        <p class="error" style="color: red; display: none">Please fill in all the required fields. <span class="italic">(* = required)</span></p>
        <a id="next" onclick="plusApp(1);" href="#">Next &#8594;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="app-box free-answers fade">

        <p class="required"></p>
        <textarea id="q1" name="Why do you want to work for us?" required></textarea>
        <p class="required"></p>
        <textarea id="q2" name="Do you have any previous working experience as your desired role? If so, please elaborate." required></textarea>
        <p class="required"></p>
        <textarea id="q3" name="What should we expect of you to bring into the team?" required></textarea>
```

From this part, all fields of the first box get submitted and written to file as expected as well as textarea q1. q2, though, does not get submitted to $_POST. Then q3 gets submitted. This isn't only happening at this particular part, but in several other places for no particular reason. Some textareas or number fields just get omitted.

My PHP:

```
<?php
require('applyHeader.php');

echo "<style>#page{display:block;}#loading{display:none;}</style>";

echo "<h1>Thank you for applying, " . $_REQUEST['First_name'] ."!</h1>";
echo "<p>Your application has been submitted and we will notify you once it is reviewed.</p>";
echo "<div class='app-box' style='display:none!important;'></div>"; // to stop jquery errors
$files = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "applications", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$file = fopen(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "applications" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . iterator_count($files) . ".txt", "a") or die("Something went wrong");

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($file, "$key: $value\n");
}

fclose($file);

require('applyFooter.php');
```

I tried:

- using $_POST and $_REQUEST, it's giving the same results.
- to vardump the contents of $_POST and it seems like the fields aren't submitting at all, not just not being written to the file.
- deleting .htaccess.
- clearing browser cache.

Comment: The name attribute in `textarea` should not be of multiple words? Right?
Try `name="something"` `name="somethingElse"` and `name="someOtherThing" ` in three textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Your form `method` have to be `post` instead of `request`.

```
<form method="post" ...>
</form>
```

Then, your could handle results with `$_POST['...']`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change form method on `post`, and rename name of textareas on something without whitespace character.And also i dont see the submit button in your form.You need this button with name `submit`.